# Maven duplicate tag "dependencies" error

Tags: java, scala, maven-2, dependencies, apache-kafka

I am trying to include apache-kafka from http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.kafka%7Ckafka_2.9.2%7C0.8.0-beta1%7CN%2FA

But when I include it in my pom.xml and run "mvn package", I get the following error:

```
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.9.2:jar:0.8.0-beta1 is invalid, transitive
 dependencies (if any) will not be available: 1 problem was encountered while building the
 effective model 

[FATAL] Non-parseable POM
 /Users/vikasr/work/more/misc/maven/scalaProject/scalaMavenTest/repository/org/apache/kafka/kafka_2.9.2/ 0.8.0-beta1/kafka_2.9.2-0.8.0-beta1.pom: 
Duplicated tag: 'dependencies' 
(position: START_TAG seen ...</dependencies>\n    <dependencies>... @36:19)  @ line 36, column 19
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Looks like maven is not happy with "dependencies" being used twice. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the console is telling you what you need to do. just remove duplicated tag `<dependencies>`, if you want to add more dependency, just add new tag `<dependency>` in existing `<dependencies>` tag!